# Exception: Function yaml_parse() does not exist

Tags: php, frameworks

Please has anyone encountered the same problem? I wanted to use the yaml_parse() function of PHP. Basically I wanted to create a big object/class(Parser) that will allow me to parse not only yaml but also json, ... etc.
So I knew that some of you suggest Symfony/Yaml, etc..., in short I find these libraries too heavy for me, especially the symfony one, I even took a look at their compose.json which also requires a lot of other libraries.
thanks in advance.[function yaml_parse does not exist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/82r99.jpg)

Comment: Did you install the YAML extension? https://www.php.net/manual/en/yaml.installation.php

Comment: Thanks, I never thought an extension was necessary.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because you cant use software that isn't installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get install php-dev php-pear libyaml-dev
sudo pecl install yamL
sudo sh -c "echo 'extension=yaml.so' >> /etc/php/7.4/cli/php.ini"
```

In `/etc/php/7.4/cli/php.ini` use your php version in the path

Comment: Thanks, I never thought an extension was necessary.

Comment: Maybe because that's only for Debian/forks.  Try it on Windows, Mac or CentOS etc...  ;-)

Comment: FYI, I had this error because I was using PHP 7.4 and not 8.0